# Subtype with Coq

Tags: coq, subtype

I try to practice `subtypes` in `Coq`, and using `ssreflect` to simplify things. But I always run into some problem when rewriting subtypes. For example:

```
Require Import Omega.
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool ssrnat eqtype.

(* a type A to build X *)
Inductive A: Set :=
| mkA: nat -> A.

Definition getNat_A (a: A) :=
match a with
| mkA n => n
end.

Inductive X: Set :=
| r1 : A -> X.

(* subtype of X that satisfying some property *)
Definition Instantiated_X (x : X) : bool :=
  match x with
  | r1 a => (getNat_A a) > 10
end.

Definition iX : Set := {x:X | (Instantiated_X x)}.

(* rewrite constructor of X, stating the fact of elements of A, under certain condition creates element of iX *)
Program Definition r1_rewrite : A -> option iX :=
fun a: A =>
 match (Instantiated_X (r1 a)) with 
 | true => Some (exist _ (r1 a) _)
 | false => None
 end.

(* try to prove r1_rewrite is surjective *)
Example r1_rewrite_surj: 
forall t : iX, exists (a : A),
 match (r1_rewrite a) with
 | None => True
 | Some e => eq t e
 end.
 Proof.
  intros.
  destruct t eqn: caseiX.
  destruct x eqn: caseX.
  exists a.
  destruct (r1_rewrite a) eqn: r_res.
   - destruct (10 < getNat_A a) eqn: guard.
     destruct i0.
     destruct x0.
     unfold r1_rewrite in r_res.
     simpl in r_res.
     rewrite <- guard in r_res. (* <- stuck *)
Abort.
```

I couldn't understand why it is stuck there. The error message saying:

```
Error: Abstracting over the term "true" leads to a term: ... 
which is ill-typed.
```

I thought Coq would replace every occurrence of `(10 < getNat_A a)` with `true` in `r_res`, which leads to something like:

```
Some (exist (fun x : X => Instantiated_X x) (r1 a)
          (r1_rewrite_obligation_1 a Heq_anonymous) =
Some (exist (fun x : X => Instantiated_X x) (r1 a0) i0)
```

and by `proof irrelevance` and `r1 injectivity`, allows my proof to go through. So, I wonder can I get some pointer about how I can massage `r_res` in this case so it facilitates rewriting.

edit: remove `Eq` type class, and its instances to make example more concise

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but maybe having a look at the `insub` and the `insubK` lemma can help. [Recall that injectivity follows from having an inverse.

Comment: Also, notice that the Eq class and its instances are not really necessary in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your proof attempt is that you have to be careful about how you rewrite.  Here is a possible solution.

```
Example r1_rewrite_surj:
forall t : iX, exists (a : A),
 match (r1_rewrite a) with
 | None => True
 | Some e => eq t e
 end.
Proof.
move=> [[a] Pa]; exists a; rewrite /r1_rewrite.
move: (erefl _); rewrite {1 3}Pa.
by move=> e; rewrite (eq_irrelevance (r1_rewrite_obligation_1 _ _) Pa).
Qed.
```

It is a bit tricky to see what is going on here.  After the first line, the proof state looks like this:

```
  a : A
  Pa : Instantiated_X (r1 a)
  ============================
  match
    (if Instantiated_X (r1 a) as b return b = Instantiated_X (r1 a) -> option iX
     then
      fun H : true = Instantiated_X (r1 a) =>
      Some (exist (fun x : X => Instantiated_X x) (r1 a) (r1_rewrite_obligation_1 a H))
     else fun _ : false = Instantiated_X (r1 a) => None) (erefl (Instantiated_X (r1 a)))
  with
  | Some e => exist (fun x : X => Instantiated_X x) (r1 a) Pa = e
  | None => True
  end
```

If we try to rewrite with `Pa` at any of the occurrences below, we will get a type error. For example:

1. If we try to replace the first occurrence of `Instantiated_X (r1 a)`, Coq will not allow us to apply the result of the `if` to `(erefl (Instantiated_X (r1 a))`.
2. We could solve the above issue by replacing the first, second, and sixth (the one on `erefl`) occurrences of `Instantiated_X (r1 a)` with `true`.  This would also not work, as it would make the application of `r1_rewrite_obligation_1` ill-typed.

The solution is to generalize over `erefl` (with the call `move: (erefl _)`), leading to the following proof state:

```
  forall e : Instantiated_X (r1 a) = Instantiated_X (r1 a),
  match
    (if Instantiated_X (r1 a) as b return b = Instantiated_X (r1 a) -> option iX
     then
      fun H : true = Instantiated_X (r1 a) =>
      Some (exist (fun x : X => Instantiated_X x) (r1 a) (r1_rewrite_obligation_1 a H))
     else fun _ : false = Instantiated_X (r1 a) => None) e
  with
  | Some e0 => exist (fun x : X => Instantiated_X x) (r1 a) Pa = e0
  | None => True
  end
```

It is probably not easy to see, but at this point it is safe to rewrite with `Pa` to replace the first and third occurrences of `Instantiated_X (r1 a)`, and allow the `if` to reduce. We can then conclude by appealing to proof irrelevance of boolean equality.

Needless to say, reasoning about typing problems in this way is a nightmare. As ejgallego pointed out, it is much easier in this case to reuse the subtyping machinery of ssreflect.  For example:

```
(* Other definitions remain the same *)
Definition r1_rewrite a : option iX := insub (r1 a).

Example r1_rewrite_surj:
forall t : iX, exists (a : A),
 match (r1_rewrite a) with
 | None => True
 | Some e => eq t e
 end.
Proof.
by move=> [[a] Pa]; exists a; rewrite /r1_rewrite insubT.
Qed.
```

The `insub` function is a generic version of your `r1_rewrite`.  It checks whether the property defining a subtype holds and, if so, pairs that object with the corresponding proof.  The `insubT` lemma says that `insub` returns a `Some` when the property holds.

Comment: Comparing `insubT` vs your approach is a good exercise, it is often the case that induction and rewrite fail is Coq because your context is not "generic enough". A good recipe for problems is to have things that depend on specific equality proofs, as oppossed to generic proofs over all `p : x = y`.